# Raphael: Dragging rectangles while keeping them connected

Tags: javascript, raphael

The intent of the following code is to drag any of the two rectangles around and keep them connected with the line. However, as you can  see in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/wrJKm/), the line moves anywhere else. What's wrong with this code?

This is the HTML

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

And this is the javascript

```
window.onload = function() {

  var paper = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600); 
  var rect1 = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 100 ).attr({"fill":"blue"});
  var rect2 = paper.rect(400, 100, 100, 100 ).attr({"fill":"green"});

  rect1.node.id = "rect1";
  rect2.node.id = "rect2";

  var x1=200, y1=150, x2=400, y2=150;
  var line = paper.path(['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2]);

  var start = function () {
        // storing original coordinates
        this.ox = this.attr("x");
        this.oy = this.attr("y");
    },
    move = function (dx, dy) {
        // move will be called with dx and dy
        this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});

        if ( this.node.id  == "rect1" ) {
            x1 += dx;
            y1 += dy;
        }
        else if ( this.node.id  == "rect2" )  {
            x2 += dx;
            y2 += dy;
        }
        line.attr("path", ['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2]);
    },
    up = function () {
        // restoring state
};


rect1.drag(move, start, up);
rect2.drag(move, start, up);

   };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

You can get the bounding box of the squares using

> Element.getBBox();

method and calculate the path values from that

```
        if ( this.node.id  == "rect1" ) {
            var bb=rect1.getBBox();
            x1=bb.x2;
            y1=bb.y+(bb.height/2);
        }
        else if ( this.node.id  == "rect2" )  {
            var bb2=rect2.getBBox();
            x2=bb2.x;
            y2=bb2.y+(bb2.height/2);
        }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wrJKm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Original didn't quite work when both were moved, I updated to use the this.ox and this.oy attributes which works consinstently.  Fiddle is fully updated too.

dx and dy are relative from the initial position, otherwise they would always have values in the range of -1 to 1 to indicate each time it's moved.  This means that your original x1, y1... etc are getting moved further and further away.  Instead, you should keep the initial positions constant and just modify them by the dx, dy:

http://jsfiddle.net/tQ9av/2/

```
if ( this.node.id  == "rect1" ) {
    n_x1 = this.ox + dx + 100;
    n_y1 = this.oy + dy + 50;
}
else if ( this.node.id  == "rect2" )  {
    n_x2 = this.ox + dx;
    n_y2 = this.oy + dy + 50;
}
line.attr("path", ['M', n_x1, n_y1, 'L', n_x2, n_y2]);
```

Comment: sorry, but your jsfiddle is not working, is it the edited version?